# GLM with inverse-logistic link

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, lm, link-function

Consider a model $$Y = inv.logit(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \dots, +\beta_dX_d) + \varepsilon,$$ where  $inv.logit(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$, and $\varepsilon\sim Gumbel$ is a centered Gumbel noice.

How can I estimate $\hat{\beta_i}$ based on some finite sample? I suppose that classical ML methods can work here, but is there some better way how to do it besides really maximizing quite an ugly multivariate function here?

Moreover, if we assume

$$Y = inv.logit(\beta_0 + f_1(X_1) + \dots, +f_d(X_d)) + \varepsilon,$$

for some smooth functions $f_i$, can we estimate them similarly as in GAM models? (this is no longer GAM model, because the noise is just additive).

Comment: This isn't a GLM. GLMs won't have additive error terms, except in some cases of quasilikelihood which this isn't. Also link function is more than a non-linear transformation, it's derivative describes a mean-variance relationship. A link transforms the expectation of the response on the LHS, not the RHS. You say that epsilon can be normal. Then you would get non-linear least squares as a maximum likelihood solution.

Comment: You are right, why didn't I think about it... Yes, GLM is quite wrong thinking here